# How to combine these two entity framework queries into one?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to combine these two lines:

```
var product = await db.Products.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.SeoName == productSeoName);
var photos = await db.Photos.Where(p => p.ProductId == product.ProductId).OrderBy(p => p.Importance).ToListAsync();
```

Inside this action method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(string productSeoName)
{

    var product = await db.Products.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.SeoName == productSeoName);
    var photos = await db.Photos.Where(p => p.ProductId == product.ProductId).OrderBy(p => p.Importance).ToListAsync();



    if (product == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var addToCart = new AddToCartViewModel
    {
        ProductPhotos = photos

    };
    return View(addToCart);
}
```

To something like this (pseudo):

```
    var product = await db.Products.OrderBy(p => p.ProductPhotos.Importance).SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.SeoName == productSeoName);
```

And:

```
var addToCart = new AddToCartViewModel
{
    ProductPhotos = product.ProductPhotos

};
```

### That is; I want to get a product and order the ProductPhotos collection for that product, all in one single line of code. How to do this?

Product model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Photo> ProductPhotos { get; set; }
}
```

Photo model:

```
public class Photo
{
    public int PhotoId { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public int Importance { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Photos would be joined to products and you can't order the join. What I do is utilize a property on my view model to return the joined data in the format I want. Something like the following:

```
public class ProductViewModel()
{
    ...
    public List<Photo> Photos { get; set; }

    public List<Photo> OrderedPhotos
    {
        get { return Photos.OrderBy(m => m.Importance); }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var product = await db.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Importance).Include("Photos").SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.SeoName == productSeoName);

// map product to an instance of `ProductViewModel`, either manually or with something
// like AutoMapper

return View(model); // where model is your instance of `ProductViewModel`
```

Notice the use of `Include` above. This tells EF to go ahead and select all the photos that belong to this product, so you don't have to issue another query for that later.

Then, in your view, you just use `OrderedPhotos` instead of `Photos`.

Comment: Groovy. I liked this: public List<Photo> Photos { get; set; }

    public List<Photo> OrderedPhotos
    {
        get { return Photos.OrderBy(m => m.Importance); }
    }. Also, you don't need Include("Photos") if you decorate your ProductPhotos property with the virtual keyword like so: public virtual List<Photo> ProductPhotos { get; set; }.

Comment: Not true. First, that only applies to the actual entity, *not* the view model. Second, virtual only allows EF to lazy load, which means it *will* lazy load the photos collection, unless told otherwise. As a result, an extra query will be issued when you first access it. `Include` forces eager loading, so that there's only one query.

Comment: Makes sense. Shit, this eager/lazy loading stuff should be taken care of automagically. Superhard to actually see what goes on behind the scenes.

Comment: Well, the thing is, sometimes you want lazy loading and sometimes you want eager loading. If EF decided for you, it would always be wrong at some point. If you want visibility into the queries that are getting run, try MiniProfiler (http://miniprofiler.com/).

Comment: I try to use IntelliTrace but the thing is too bloody unuserfriendly. Will take a look at miniprofiler see if it's any better.